# Designate between 2 diff lists- CSS/HTML

Tags: css, tags, target

If I add another list,how can I make sure it's the list I edit in CSS? Do I assign another `div id=?` I don't think this will work as In order to edit the TEXT (everything else works in the navbar section besides text-changes) in the `dev="navbar`, I have to edit the "li {" instead, so if I add another list..how do I target it for changes? Also,I know it's not "properly" formatted, but I'm just trying to understand here.

Here are two images:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Psb3.png)
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sOIp.png)

I'm confused why I cannot change any of the Li text properties in the #navbar selection? It forces me to make a

li{ designation in order to get that to change.

Comment: your question is bit confusing...are you trying to add two list like two `<ul>` or two `<li>` in single `<ul>` ??

Comment: I want to add a side-bar list, so another <ul>

Comment: So what is the problem just add another `<ul>` with unique class and change css according to it.

Comment: It will only let me change list colors in CSS if I do

Comment: It will only let me change list colors in CSS if I do  {li  color:x . But if I try using sidebar.{color or navbar{color  to change font color I get nothing.